# Payout Algorithm Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im building a rails app that has users and scores. I want the top half of the users to get paid out. I have a separate tiebreaker input stored for each user if they get happen to tie for last place (last paid out place). For example, I need help, if their are 8 users and 4th and 5th tie in points. Then it calls my tiebreaker.

This is what I have tried:

First I am counting the users and determening the top half of the players:

```
theUsersCount = ParticipatingUser.where(game_id: game_id).size
numofWinners = theUsersCount / 2
```

Then I am taking the users and their scores and pushing it to an array then only showing the top half of the users that won.

```
  userscores.push("#{user.username}" => playerScore})
userscores[0..numofWinners].sort_by { |y| y[:score] }
```

But I am unsure of how to take execute the tiebreaker if their is a tie for last place.

Comment: Do you know how to check for ties? If so, what's the issue?

Comment: No. I dont. Well I do. But I dont know how to check for last place ties. I dont care about the ties that are in the top half, nor do I care about the ties in the bottom half. Just need to check for ties in the last place payout and thats what I need help with.

Comment: What's the difference between last place ties and, not-last-place ties?

Comment: Top 4/8 get paid out. I need to check if 4th ties with 5,6,7,8. 

Lol think I got it actually. Sorry just being dumb.. Thank yall for helping just had a brain fart! Thanks a lot though :)

Comment: @user3591126 It's called [rubber ducking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Often times trying to elucidate the issue is enough to come up with the solution, especially when you're trying to explain it to someone who doesn't quite understand what you mean (like me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>To get the users count you should use `count` rather than `size` - `size` fetches all the rows, then counts them, while `count` counts the rows in the DB, and returns the number:</strike>

```
user_count = ParticipatingUser.where(game_id: game_id).count
```

(actually - the above is wrong - [here](http://batsov.com/articles/2014/02/17/the-elements-of-style-in-ruby-number-13-length-vs-size-vs-count/#comment-1248998887) is an explanation - you *should* use `size` which smartly chooses between `length` and `count` - thanks @nzifnab)

Now, find the score of the user in the `user_count/2` place

```
minimal_score = ParticipatingUser.order(:score, :desc).pluck(:score).take(user_count/2).last
```

And take all the users with this score or more:

```
winning_users = ParticipatingUser.where('score >= ?', minimal_score).order(:score, :desc)
```

now check if there are more users than expected:

```
if winning_users.size > user_count/2
```

then break your ties:

```
 tie_breaker(winning_users[user_count/2-1..-1])
```

All together:

```
user_count = ParticipatingUser.where(game_id: game_id).size
minimal_score = ParticipatingUser.order(:score, :desc).pluck(:score).take(user_count/2).last

winning_users = ParticipatingUser.where('score >= ?', minimal_score).order(:score, :desc)

if winning_users.size > user_count/2
  losers = tie_breaker(winning_users[user_count/2-1..-1])
  winning_users -= losers
end
winning_users
```

Comment: Wow! This is great! Thankyou so much. I was actually thinking of a different way but may use this approach! Thank you :)

Comment: Actually `size` will do the exact same thing as count - it'll use a `COUNT()` query to fetch the number of rows.  I think it might only count the records themselves via ruby if they have already been fetched.